# ICU expression *select* not detecting empty value

Tags: icu, angular-i18n, messageformat.js

I am translating my app using i18n angular 7, and I'm having problems with a ICU expression *select*. The issue is that I want the condition to recognize and empty value like this: `animal: string`

```
<div i18n="@@example> 
    { animal, select, EMPTY { Cat } dog { Dog } other { Pig } }
</div>
```

I have tried using

```
{ animal, select, undefined { Cat } dog { Dog } other { Pig } }
```

but it didn't work

when animal is:

**(empty string, null or undefined)** -> translate Cat

**dog** -> translate Dog

**other** -> translate Pig

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately it seems that the key for each translation case of the select is taken as a string, not an expression, so your `undefined` there is taken as `"undefined"`, and `EMPTY` as `"EMPTY"`.

As a workaround you can evaluate `animal + ""` as your select condition.  `undefined + "" === "undefined"`, and it will match `"undefined"` in your select cases:

`{ animal + "", select, undefined { Cat } dog { Dog } other { Pig } }`

That said, you could convert `undefined` to any string value you think won't actually appear in the `animal` variable for the same result:

`{ animal === undefined? "geranium" : animal  , select, geranium { Cat } dog { Dog } other { Pig } }`